# Trying to disable a button after clicking in react

Tags: reactjs

So one of my last goals in my current project is to disable my nominate button after I click it and add the movie to the new nominations array. I'm stuck on how I should go about this. The code is below

this is the main page where all of my components are rendered and functions are made.

```
function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [movieSearch, setMovieSearch] = useState('');
  const [nominations, setNominations] = useState([])

  const getMovieRequest = async () => {
    const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movieSearch}&apikey=9d2fd6c8`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    if (responseJson.Search) {
      setMovies(responseJson.Search);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovieRequest(movieSearch);
  }, [movieSearch]);

  const nominateMovie = (movie) => {
    const newNominationsArray = [...nominations, movie];
    setNominations(newNominationsArray);
  }

  const removeMovie = (movie) => {
    const newNominationsArray = nominations.filter((nominated) => nominated.imdbID !== movie.imdbID);
    setNominations(newNominationsArray);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (nominations.length === 5) {
      document.getElementById("alert").style.setProperty("display", "flex")
    } else if (nominations.length < 5) {
      document.getElementById("alert").style.setProperty("display", "none")
    }
  }, [nominations])


  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <SearchBar
          movieSearch={movieSearch}
          setMovieSearch={setMovieSearch} />
        <Alert />
        <div className="row">
          <Nominations length={nominations.length} handleRemoveClick={removeMovie} removeNomination={RemoveNomination} nominations={nominations} />
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <ResultsList nominations={nominations} movies={movies} handleNominationsClick={nominateMovie} nominateButton={NominateButton} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This next code calls the api when a user enters into the input box and responds with data. A nominate button is generated underneath each title and when you click on it, it adds to the new nominations array defined in App

```
const ResultsList = (props) => {
    const NominateButton = props.nominateButton
    return (
       <>
       {props.movies.map((movie, index) =>
        <div className=" image-container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-3">
           <img src={movie.Poster} alt="movie-poster"></img>
           <button onClick={() => props.handleNominationsClick(movie)} className="overlay d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
               <NominateButton  />
           </button>
       </div>
       )}
       </>
      
    )
}
```

Not sure if this one will be useful but this is the nominate button component.

```
const NominateButton = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <span className="mr-2">Nominate</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-plus-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3h-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3v3a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-3h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3v-3z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NominateButton
```

if you need more information the repo can be found here https://github.com/oballematt/the-shoppies

Comment: you could pass down `nominations` and do `disabled={nominations.includes(movie)}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use "disabled" as an Attribute in button it will disabled after click

<button disabled={this.state.}

Answer (score 0):

theress a attribute  `disabled` in button .
you need to set it true or false according to you states .i.e you will be maintaining a state variable for disabling the button .

`< button disabled = {this.state.isClicked} />`

[you can read more here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/react-tips-disable-buttons-formdata-types-for-function-6c8f23d13b64#:%7E:text=We%20can%20disable%20a%20button,disabled%20prop%20of%20the%20button.&text=We%20pass%20in%20the%20value,inputted%20into%20the%20form%20field.)